# Ways to check if a rabbitmq server is alive

Tags: rabbitmq

Using Java the spring-rabbitmq has a isRunning method in the RabbitTemplate class. Is this method equivalent to rabbitmq’s server-check  through http-api: /api/aliveness-test/vhost? Can both be used for the purpose of just checking if the rabbitmq server is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are different things.

RabbitTemplate's class is checking if any of RabbitMQ listeners in your application are still running.

```
    synchronized (this.directReplyToContainers) {
        return this.directReplyToContainers.values()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(AbstractMessageListenerContainer::isRunning);
    }
```

API check through HTTP checks vhost's (server's) aliveness.